# Convert a black and white image to array of numbers?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[image: The image is 28 pixels by 28 pixels. They can interpret this as a big array of numbers:]
Like the image above suggests, how can I convert the image to the left into an array that represent the darkness of the image between `0 for white` and `decimals for darker colours closer to 1? as shown in the image using`python 3`?

Update:
I have tried to work abit more on this. There are good answers below too.

```
# Load image 
filename = tf.constant("one.png")
image_file = tf.read_file(filename)

# Show Image
Image("one.png")

#convert method
def convertRgbToWeight(rgbArray):
    arrayWithPixelWeight = []
    for i in range(int(rgbArray.size / rgbArray[0].size)):
        for j in range(int(rgbArray[0].size / 3)):
            lum = 255-((rgbArray[i][j][0]+rgbArray[i][j][1]+rgbArray[i][j][2])/3) # Reversed luminosity
            arrayWithPixelWeight.append(lum/255) # Map values from range 0-255 to 0-1

    return arrayWithPixelWeight



# Convert image to numbers and print them
image_decoded_png = tf.image.decode_png(image_file,channels=3)
image_as_float32 = tf.cast(image_decoded_png, tf.float32)

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
sess = tf.Session()
squeezedArray = sess.run(image_as_float32)

convertedList = convertRgbToWeight(squeezedArray)

print(convertedList) # This will give me an array of numbers.
```

Comment: What image format?

Comment: I guess your image as already been interpolated on the left to obtain the smooth border right? you can use numpy package to manage python data efficiently. Then I guess you'll have to interpolate the values taking into account the neighborhood.

Comment: @samthegoodone see my answer

Comment: Can you please see my answer. I have updated the question with a possible answer. Please comment if this is also a possible way to do it with tensorflow

Comment: @SamTheGoodOne Just curious about why you would do simple Image processing task such as this with TensorFlow. Much easier with cv/NumPy.

Comment: Your question after the edit is more unfocused. Before you were asking how to do something. Now you're also asking if your way is okay. Why? Do you get an incorrect result? Does it seem verbose or inefficient? What are your criteria for choosing what is an acceptable answer?

Comment: I may have misunderstood. There are two good answers. Will edit again and make my edit as a possible solution. The main question is to answer the first part before the update.  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend to read in images with opencv. The biggest advantage of opencv is that it supports multiple image formats and it automatically transforms the image into a numpy array. For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_path = '/YOUR/PATH/IMAGE.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0) # read image as grayscale. Set second parameter to 1 if rgb is required
```

Now `img` is a numpy array with values between `0 - 255`. By default 0 equals black and 255 equals white. To change this you can use the opencv built in function `bitwise_not`:

```
img_reverted= cv2.bitwise_not(img)
```

We can now scale the array with:

```
new_img = img_reverted / 255.0  // now all values are ranging from 0 to 1, where white equlas 0.0 and black equals 1.0
```

Comment: This would result in white pixels having the value of 1, whereas the question wants 1 for black pixels.

Comment: Can you please see my answer. I have updated the question with a possible answer. Please comment if this is also a possible way to do it with tensorflow

Comment: @SamTheGoodOne for me, without testing, your code seems reasonable. But as you probably noticed it is much harder to do the image processing with tensorflow. That's why i highly recommend the usage of opencv. It makes your life much easier ;)

Comment: I’m new to tensorflow and python . Your solution is really nice.

Answer (score 3):

### Load the image and then just invert and divide by 255.

Here is the image (`'Untitled.png'`) that I used for this example: https://ufile.io/h8ncw

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_img = cv2.imread('Untitled.png') 
inverted_img = (255.0 - my_img)  
final = inverted_img / 255.0

# Visualize the result
plt.imshow(final)
plt.show()

print(final.shape)
(661, 667, 3)
```

### Results (final object represented as image):

[image: final image]

Comment: This would result in white pixels having the value of 1, whereas the question wants 1 for black pixels.

Comment: see again my answer.

Comment: Why downvoting? any explanation? it's my answer exact ?

Comment: I actually upvoted your answer. Makes perfect sense to me. Eludes me why someone would downvote it.

Comment: Me too. Especially when they don't leave a comment to explain why. Thanks mate

Comment: Can you please see my answer. I have updated the question with a possible answer. Please comment if this is also a possible way to do it with tensorflow

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer to the original question as stated. I would have written it myself, but Daniel got there first with the idea, so I left him a comment to flesh it out a bit more. My only suggestion is that plotting the result distracts from the answer as it's more about getting float numbers and the plot will have inverted colours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL package to manage images. Here's example how it can be done.

```python
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('sample.png')
width, height = image.size
pixels = image.load()

# Check if has alpha, to avoid "too many values to unpack" error
has_alpha = len(pixels[0,0]) == 4

# Create empty 2D list
fill = 1
array = [[fill for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if has_alpha:
            r, g, b, a = pixels[x,y]
        else:
            r, g, b = pixels[x,y]
        lum = 255-((r+g+b)/3) # Reversed luminosity
        array[y][x] = lum/255 # Map values from range 0-255 to 0-1
```

I think it works but please note that the only test I did was if values are in desired range:

```python
# Test max and min values
h, l = 0,1
for row in array:
    h = max([max(row), h])
    l = min([min(row), l])
print(h, l)
```

Comment: Can you please see my answer. I have updated the question with a possible answer. Please comment if this is also a possible way to do it with tensorflow.

Answer (score -1):

You have to load the image from the path and then transform it to a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

The values of the image will be between 0 and 255. The next step is to standardize the numpy array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would help if you fleshed out your answer a bit more, i.e., by explaining or showing how to normalise the array. It'd make it more complete, as someone who doesn't know what that means would have to resort to third-party sources to learn. You should also point out that 0 refers to black and white to 255, since the questions seems to want white = 0 and black = 1.